# Wrong arrow length using quiver with cartopy projections

Tags: python, cartopy

I want to plot a vector field with vectors representing a displacement between one point to another on the map with `cartopy`.

My code works as expected when using the `PlateCarree()` transformation, but arrow length is several orders of magnitude off for all the other projections I tested.

Here is a MWE that should illustrate quite clearly the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

import numpy

# Want to test for several different projections
projections = [
    ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    ccrs.EqualEarth(),
    ccrs.Mollweide(),
    ccrs.AzimuthalEquidistant(),
]
# ALl the coordinates will be given in the PlateCarree coordinate system.
coordinate_ccrs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

# We want N**2 points over the latitude/longitude values.
N = 5
lat, lon = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.linspace(-80, 80, N), numpy.linspace(-170, 170, N))
lat, lon = lat.flatten(), lon.flatten()

# We want arrows to appear, let make a small perturbation and try
# to do an arrow from (lon, lat) to (lon + perturbation, lat + perturbation).
rng = numpy.random.default_rng()
perturbation_amplitude = 10
lat_perturbation = perturbation_amplitude * rng.random(N * N)
lon_perturbation = perturbation_amplitude * rng.random(N * N)

# Create the matplotlib figure and axes, no projection for the moment as this
# will be changed later.
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axes = axes.flatten()

for i, projection in enumerate(projections):
    # Replace the existing ax with an ax with the desired projection.
    ax = axes[i]
    fig.delaxes(ax)
    ax = axes[i] = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i + 1, projection=projection)
    # Make the plot readable.
    ax.set_global()
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels="x")

    # Non pertubed points are plotted in black.
    ax.plot(lon, lat, "k.", ms=5, transform=coordinate_ccrs)
    # Perturbed points are plotted in red.
    ax.plot(
        lon + lon_perturbation,
        lat + lat_perturbation,
        "r.",
        ms=5,
        transform=coordinate_ccrs,
    )
    # We try to draw arrows from a given black dot to its corresponding
    # red dot.
    ax.quiver(
        lon,
        lat,
        lon_perturbation,
        lat_perturbation,
        transform=coordinate_ccrs,
        # From https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html?highlight=quiver#matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver
        # look at the documentation of the "scale_unit" parameter.
        # The next 3 parameters are what matplotlib tell us to do. From
        # matplotlib documentation:
        #   To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units
        #   as x and y, use angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1.
        angles="xy",
        scale_units="xy",
        scale=1,
        # Simply make the arrows nicer, removing these last 3 parameters do not
        # solve the issue.
        minshaft=2,
        minlength=0.5,
        width=0.002,
    )

# Show everything
plt.show()
```

which display on the screen the following image:

[image]

The `PlateCarree` transformation is the only one displaying arrows. In fact, there are arrows in the other 3 projections, but I order to see them I need to scale them by 10000 with `scale=0.00001` in the call to `quiver`, which gives:

[image]

Did I make a mistake when using `cartopy` API, is this expected behaviour and I missed something in the documentation, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while there's quite some debate on github about cartopy's implementation of quiver-plot transformations [GitHub-issues](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+quiver) there is in fact a way on how to get your plot look as you want it to look...

However, while thinking about this... I noticed that there's a thing that you might want to consider when using projected quiver-plots...

As I see it, the re-projected arrows would would most probably need to be curved to really visualize the same direction as provided in the original data!

(in the input-crs the arrow points as a straight line from point A to B, but if you re-project the points, the "straight line" that connected A and B is now in general a curved line, and so if the original direction was correct, I think the new direction should be indicated as a curved arrow...)

That being said, you could achieve what you want by transforming the points manually instead of letting cartopy do the job:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

import numpy

# Want to test for several different projections
projections = [
    ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    ccrs.EqualEarth(),
    ccrs.Mollweide(),
    ccrs.AzimuthalEquidistant(),
]
# ALl the coordinates will be given in the PlateCarree coordinate system.
coordinate_ccrs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

# We want N**2 points over the latitude/longitude values.
N = 5
lat, lon = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.linspace(-80, 80, N), numpy.linspace(-170, 170, N))
lat, lon = lat.flatten(), lon.flatten()

# We want arrows to appear, let make a small perturbation and try
# to do an arrow from (lon, lat) to (lon + perturbation, lat + perturbation).
rng = numpy.random.default_rng()
perturbation_amplitude = 10
lat_perturbation = perturbation_amplitude * rng.random(N * N)
lon_perturbation = perturbation_amplitude * rng.random(N * N)

# Create the matplotlib figure and axes, no projection for the moment as this
# will be changed later.
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axes = axes.flatten()

for i, projection in enumerate(projections):
    # Replace the existing ax with an ax with the desired projection.
    ax = axes[i]
    fig.delaxes(ax)
    ax = axes[i] = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i + 1, projection=projection)
    # Make the plot readable.
    ax.set_global()
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels="x")

    # Non pertubed points are plotted in black.
    ax.plot(lon, lat, "k.", ms=5, transform=coordinate_ccrs)
    # Perturbed points are plotted in red.
    ax.plot(
        lon + lon_perturbation,
        lat + lat_perturbation,
        "r.",
        ms=5,
        transform=coordinate_ccrs,
    )
    
    
    xy_start = projection.transform_points(coordinate_ccrs, lon, lat)[:,:-1].T
    xy_end = projection.transform_points(coordinate_ccrs, lon + lon_perturbation, 
                                         lat + lat_perturbation)[:,:-1].T
    
    # We try to draw arrows from a given black dot to its corresponding
    # red dot.
    ax.quiver(
        *xy_start, 
        *(xy_end - xy_start),
        # From https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html?highlight=quiver#matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver
        # look at the documentation of the "scale_unit" parameter.
        # The next 3 parameters are what matplotlib tell us to do. From
        # matplotlib documentation:
        #   To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units
        #   as x and y, use angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1.
        angles="xy",
        scale_units="xy",
        scale=1,
        # Simply make the arrows nicer, removing these last 3 parameters do not
        # solve the issue.
        minshaft=2,
        minlength=0.5,
        width=0.002,
    )

# Show everything
plt.show()
```

[image]